# Unity - Multi-resolution support strategies for 2d games

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

I am trying to target a wide range of resolutions for a 2d titles we are starting to work on with Unity. I previously worked with different middlewares and I am trying to achieve something like the 'Fixed Height' strategy that can be found in Cocos2D-X (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support).

I would like to know, in your opinion, what would be the easiest way to support a wide range of resolutions and display ratios using a minimum of different graphical assets with Unity 4.3 for a 2d title.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could not use UGUI, you can select NGUI or other GUI engines. NGUI support fixed resolution with UIRoot. For examples, you can setup scaling style to Constrained on mobiles, content with to 960 fit, content height to 640 fit in UIRoot.

Otherwise, if you can select UGUI, you can use more flexible methods like Canvas Scaler, Rect transform.

Comment: Canvas Scaler was pretty much was I was looking for. Thanks!